How to solve the "SASS: Deprecation The legacy JS API" Warning?
I have this project I've been building with the T3 Stack (Next JS / Vercel / etc.).
And as many of us, I got now this warning SASS Deprecation on Dart Sass 2.0.0.
I've seen many people suggesting silencing the warnings. But wouldn't that just postpone a problem? Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't this just break your code once you bring the 2.0 Sass update to it?
What I'm trying to understand is how to fix it. (Not silence it).
I've tried to change my Sass imports to @use / @forward instead, as recommended on Sass documentation. But then my app crashes.
I've also seen some solutions for people using vite to add to their vite.config a option
   export default defineConfig({
        css: {
            preprocessorOptions: {
                scss: {
                    api: 'modern-compiler' // or "modern"
                } 
            }
        }
    })

I've tried that on my next config but no success, the error is still there.
Also tried an educated guess with this one.

    /** @type {import("next").NextConfig} */
    const config = {
        sassOptions: {
            preprocessorOptions: {
                sass: {              
                    api: "modern",
                },
            },
         },
     };


But the error is still there and I can't refactor my @imports to @use or @forward
I don't mind refactoring all my @imports to @use or @forward. As I want to keep the project fresh with new technology standards.
But how can I set this to work on my NextJS (T3 Stack) project?
How would you guys go about config files on a T3 Stack (NextJS) Project?

This seems to be an 'internal nextjs thing' that you should not be too concerned  about. Once they migrate it 'under the hood' there may be some impacts in a nextjs release.
You mentionned not wishing to silence it, but in case you change your mind, there is this option in your next.config.js :
 sassOptions: {
    silenceDeprecations: ["legacy-js-api"],
  },

Read more on this here :
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/67931
and here :
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/71638
